# ¿Existen palabras de uso común que contengan las cinco diferentes vocales?

Tags: palabras-raras

¿Existen palabras de uso común que contengan las cinco diferentes vocales?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El diccionario de la RAE recoge 1420 palabras con las cinco vocales. Son muchas menos que las que aporta [angus en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3170/106) porque aquí no se incluyen todas las conjugaciones, enclíticos, etc.

Como preguntas por palabras de uso común, te pongo aquí las diez primeras por su frecuencia de uso en el español, según el [corpus CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/lfrecuencias.html):

- consecuencia
- ayuntamiento
- funcionamiento
- preocupación
- estadounidense
- entusiasmo
- revolucionario
- documentación
- educativo
- universitario
- ...

Answer (score 6):

Sí, existen. Por ejemplo: `murciélago`, `abuelito`, `arquitecto`...

[Aquí](http://www.solosequenosenada.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/palabras_con_todas_las_vocales.txt) hay una lista con más de 40.000 palabras pentavocálicas.

Answer (score 3):

Mi aporte para complementar lo ya dicho (que, en realidad, ya es suficiente).

Partiendo de las [10.000 palabras más frecuentes](http://corpus.rae.es/frec/10000_formas.TXT) (entre las que no se encuentra el famoso *murciélago*), considerando sólo las que tienen **las 5 vocales sin repetirse** y quitando todas las 'u' mudas, obtenemos las siguientes 23 palabras, en orden de frecuencia:

- educación
- comunidades
- entusiasmo
- auténtico(s)
- regulación
- educativo(s)
- refugiado (refugiados, refugiando)
- estudiado (estudiados, estudiando)
- republicano(s)
- agricultores
- secundario(s)
- mantuvieron
- acudieron
- vestuario
- superación
- euforia
- denunciado (denunciados, denunciando)
- comunicarse
- funcionales
- ecuación
- anticuerpo(s)
- precaución
- concurrencia

Answer (score 2):

Incluso hay nombres propios, como Aurelio, Eustaquio, Eulalio, Eulogia, Orihuela ...